# Automatic Pr's in Azure Repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos

Is it possible to create automatic pull requests against a specific branch on Azure Repos as PR triggers do not work in Azure Repos. I am new to working with Azure repos and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Under what circumstances? Have you looked at the REST APIs?

Comment: What do you mean by "Automatic" in relation to PR?

Comment: So it should be similar to a pr trigger, whenever I run a build pipeline it should create a pull request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to directly do it on Azure Devops, but you can use Create [Pull Request extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) to create Pull Request whenever you do a build.